# dijkstra on a grid

Tags: algorithm, graph, grid, dijkstra

There's no point in using a priority queue if I'm running dijskstra's algroithm on a 'grid' right?

A grid would be a map like this:
Vertexes:

```
 ___________________
|A|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|C|B|_|_|_|_|E|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|D|_|_|_|_|_|F|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
```

Edges:

```
A <-> C
C <-> B
C <-> D
D <-> F
B <-> E
E <-> F
```

In other words, a map where each edge connects to a vertex that is horizontal or vertical from it, but can not connect diagonally (for example an edge from A to B or A to F would not be allowed).

Additionally, the weights of the edges are intuitive to their location in the grid. For example the edge weight from A <-> C is 1, C <-> B is 1, C <-> D is 6, B <-> E is 5 and D <->F and E <-> F are both 6.

I implemented dijsktra's algorithm awhile ago for graphs like this and I now need to optimize it so that it is as fast as possible. My current implementation (ruby):

```
def self.dj_start(g,source, goal)
    t = Time.now
    visited, distances, paths, already_queued = {}, {}, {}, {}

    curr = g.verticies[source]
    queue = [] # 

    queue.push(curr)
    already_queued[curr] = true
    distances[curr] = 0
    paths[curr] = curr
    @count = 0
    while(!queue.empty?)
      run_dijkstra(g, visited, distances, paths, queue, already_queued, goal)
    end
    t = Time.now - t
    print "ran dijkstra in #{t}s count = #{@count}\n"
    return [paths, distances]
end

def self.run_dijkstra(g, visited, distances, paths, queue, already_queued, goal)
curr = g.verticies[queue.delete_at(0)]
visited[curr] = true

curr.edges.each do |e|
    @count+=1
      if !already_queued[e.vertex] && !visited[e.vertex]
        queue.push(e.vertex) 
        already_queued[e.vertex] = true
      end

      nd = e.weight+distances[curr]
      if distances[e.vertex].nil? || nd < distances[e.vertex]
        distances[e.vertex] = nd
        paths[e.vertex] = curr

        if e.vertex.eql?(goal) # minor optimization
          queue = []
          return 1 # Code for exit due to this very minor optimization
        end
      end # end distance check
end
```

end

I was going to rewrite it with a priority queue, but I just don't see the need in doing so. Or am I missing something?

Comment: what are you using to maintain the list of all possible next vertices? any why wouldn't you need to pick the entry with the smallest distance?

Comment: I'm failing to understand the benefits I would gain if I used a priority queue here instead of just enqueuing and dequeing as I am right now.

Comment: you are then not doing a dijkstra, if you have different weights on the edges you have to, if not all is fine and you are doing BFS.

Answer (score 0):

Usually similar problems are solved using a breadth-first search where each cell is a vertex in the graph. Still in the problem you are solving the number of valid positions is really low with comparison to the number of cells in the grid so maybe your approach could work. Please note that the edge weights(i.e. the minimum number of cells you need to travel between to positions) should be provided to your program somehow. If that is not the case you will have to calculate these using BFS and thus there is no point in the Dijkstra.

Having said that, I will answer your question. If the edges are provided in the way you show here, there is a reason to use priority queue. It will decrease the computational complexity of the algorithm by an order of magnitude. This will be obvious for larger grids.

By the way there is a really cool gem for ruby that implements fibonacci heap. Although it might be huge overkill to use fibonacci heap for grpahs the size you show here I always though it would be cool to have a fibonacci-heap-based dijkstra.

Hope this answer helps.

Comment: I just realized all I am actually doing is a breadth-first search and looking at my code it should be running in O(|E|+|V|). Using the dijikstra's with a min heap would be excessive then?

Comment: No need for dijkstra in this case.